# Attaching a file to an email coming from ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have an ActionResult, which returns a generated PDF file:

```
public ActionResult PdfById(int id)
{    
   ....
   return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", fileName);
}
```

is there a way to attach said file to an email as an attachment?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Do you mean on the client or server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up with the solution after some googling and tinkering. Hope some will find this useful as well.

```
var contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);

var attachmentFile = PdfById(id);
var attachmentStream = new MemoryStream((attachmentFile as FileContentResult).FileContents);
var attachmentTitle = (attachmentFile as FileContentResult).FileDownloadName;

var message = new MailMessage();
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentStream, attachmentTitle, contentType.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check inside `System.Net.Mail` namespace, and use the `SmtpClient` class. It is possible to fill a `MailMessage` class, which can  have attachments, and then you can send it. 
It is possible to configure the SMTP Server data either directly in the configuration file (.config) of your application, or programmatically from your code it-self.